# phpMyadmin database import error #1046 - No database selected

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin

I have an sql file that i exported from phpmyadmin on another computer.  I tried to import the file on this computer and I get this error:

```
Error
```

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `phplogin`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `people`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `people` (

 `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `name` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
 `age` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `testvar` VARCHAR( 5 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =3;

MySQL said: 

#1046 - No database selected
```

Answer (score 76):

The error is because you either didn't select a database on the left side to import to, and/or you didn't create the empty database first. Create a database in phpMyAdmin called "phplogin", select it on the left side, and then run the import.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in a phpMyAdmin configuration that only logs into a specific database? (Thus there is no DB to select on the left, only tables.)

Comment: Also, what if there was no database to select in the first place? I made an entire export of my entire phpmyadmin collection, and reformatted my computer. When I try to import the file, I get the same message. I need it to create the database tables for me, as I can't go through and add each one exactly as it was.. Why didnt this get included in the export?

Answer (score 4):

Append the following line to the beginning of your sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE phplogin;
```

These problems can be resolved by exporting the SQL file while being outside the database.Then phpmyadmin automatically appends the above statement to the SQL file

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem just this moment and none of the above answers solved my problem. Eventually, I ran the export again and the resulting .sql file was much larger. So the problem was a faulty export which resulted in an incomplete SQL file. The necessary statements would have been truncated in this case.