# Error when importing sql database to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble when trying to import a database into phpmyadmin.

```
Error
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `iiumcms`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `admin`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `admin` (

 `fname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `email` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `admin_no` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `dept_id` VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
 `username` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
 `password` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `admin_no` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =7;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear, you have to select a database in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: did you mean that i need to create a database name iiumcms and only after that i can import the database iiumcms?

Comment: yes exactly.  MySQL always has to operate within the context of a selected database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant import phpmyadmin database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880511/cant-import-phpmyadmin-database)

Answer (score 5):

You have to create an empty database with name 'iiumcms' in your PhpMyAdmin and have to select this database in left sidebar before importing your .sql file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first select your database, then import file.

In MySQL you can use this statement:

```
USE `iiumcms`;
```

If you don't have this database created, you have to do it first.

Answer (score 1):

This error when o didn't tells to mysql what is the database to do the restore.
You need put:

```
USE `your_database_name`;
```

at the begin of your file.

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, this means choosing a database from the sidebar and then using its import tab. If the database you want to fill doesn't exist, you have to create it first using the `Create new database` form.